# Ruby multiple print on the same line

Tags: ruby, printing

Is there an easy way for Ruby to print in one line, then for the next print, it prints to the same line from the beginning.

I am trying to make a simple file counter shown on the stdout while files are being generated. It looks like a rapidly updated number at the same position on the screen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

could use  \r..

```
while(true) do
  print "\\\r"
  print "|\r"
  print "/\r"
end
```

Will print the char and then move the cursor back and print over it, making a little spinner like thing.  Else you can look at something like curses.... (https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse for a ruby wrapper)

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this:

```
print "Hello"
print 13.chr
print "123"
```

If your console supports line feed it should then replace the first chars and print "123lo". An example with a counter might look as follows:

```
100.times{|x| print x; print 13.chr; sleep 0.01}
```

Comment: Irritatingly, this works locally on Ubuntu but does not behave on SUSE via SSH. BTW - isn't a CR rather than an LF

Answer (score 0):

If you're printing to a terminal-like thing you can use control characters, or curses. If you know how many items you're processing it might be easier to just make a textual progress bar, though, like wget/etc.